# A method which returns a Vector of all the shortest strings in a Vector of Strings

Tags: java

I am passing a vector of strings `b` and then I am iterating the list to find the smallest string. and question says I need to return all the string of that smallest length. Then I am adding the strings to the list `a` and then returning the list.

```
public static Vector<String> q(Vector<String> b){
        Vector<String> a = new Vector<String>();
        int small = 0;

        if(b.size() > 0){
            small = b.get(0).length();
        }


        for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++)
        {
            if(small > b.get(i).length()){
                small = b.get(i).length();
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++)
        {
            if(small == b.get(i).length()){
                a.add(b.get(i));
            }
        }

        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use of obsolete `java.util.Vector`

`java.util.Vector` is obsolete, albeit not deprecated, and the preferred replacement is `java.util.ArrayList`. For more info, see this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275).

I assume the interface is fixed, so I'll keep the `Vector`. It shouldn't be difficult to switch to `ArrayList` anyway.

#### Non-descriptive identifier names

`q`, `b` and `a` are bad identifier names. The name of a variable or function should indicate its purpose. Try to find more meaningful names for identifiers. For example the function `q` could be renamed to `selectAllShortest`, `a` could be `result` if nothing better, etc.

#### Inconsistent indent style

You use K&R style with function body and with `if`:

> ```
> public static Vector<String> q(Vector<String> b){
> ```
>
> ```
> if(b.size() > 0){
> ```

but Allman with `for`:

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++)
> {
> ```

Although this is to great extent a matter of personal preference, you will probably find sooner or later that it's useful to have a unified style used throughout your code. Then you don't have to bother about whether it's an `if` or a `for`, or function, class, etc.

#### First string processed twice

The way you initialize `small`, you check the length of the first string twice.

> ```
> if(b.size() > 0){
>     small = b.get(0).length();  // first time
> }
>
> for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++)
> {
>     if(small > b.get(i).length()){   // second time
> ```

Instead you can start the loop from `1`:

```
for (int i = 1; i < b.size(); i++) {
    ...
```

#### Not using variables where you should

In the loops, you can save the string's length into a variable to avoid retrieving it twice:

> ```
> if(small > b.get(i).length()){
>     small = b.get(i).length();
> ```

Could be written as:

```
int len = b.get(i).length();

if (len < small) {
    small = len;
}
```

Many people, including myself, also find the second way more readable.

#### Manually iterating over vector

This old-school index-based iteration over vector:

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++)
> {
>     if(small > b.get(i).length()){
>         small = b.get(i).length();
>     }
> }
> ```

can be simplified using a for-each loop:

```
for (String s : b) {
    if (s.length() < small) {
        small = s.length();
    }
}
```

#### Can be done in one pass

You don't have to iterate over the vector twice. Depending on the specific situation, it might be more efficient to save all the shortest strings into the result vector `a` during the first pass.

Initially you set `small` to some large number, eg. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. The `String.length` method returns an `int`, so `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is de facto the maximum possible length of a `String`. Then iterate over the strings: if the current string is shorter than `small`, you remove all strings from `a` and add the current string. Otherwise, if the current string is the same length as `small`, you just add it to `a`.

---

Here's the modified version:

```
public static Vector<String> selectAllShortest(Vector<String> strings) {

    Vector<String> result = new Vector<String>();
    int minLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (String s : strings) {
        int len = s.length();

        if (len == minLen) {
            result.add(s);
        }
        else if (len < minLen) {
            minLen = len;
            result.clear();
            result.add(s);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! You read my mind and answered every bit of my query

Comment: I couldn't have written a better answer myself.